# Vuejs in production: prefix static path

Tags: webpack, vue.js

#### Context

I'm building a VueJS app and I would like to push it in production. I've generated files using `npm run build` and I've uploaded those on a server (IIS).

I have a lot of other applications on this server and I **can't** change how it works.

Here is a fake example to help me explain my issue:

`mydomain.com/app1` will redirect to a web-app under a folder `app1`.
To add my VueJS project I've created a new folder - lets say `vueapp` - and I get access it via `mydomain.com/vueapp`.

The thing is : the static paths generated by vue are **not** prefixed by `vueapp`. Paths in `index.html` are not like I want : I get `mydomain.com/static/**` instead of `mydomaim.com/vueapp/static/**` for a vue request.

I would like to tell webpack to prefix `index.html`'s path by something but I can't get it work.

#### assetsSubDirectory

`config/build.js` gives us the possibility to change the assets sub directory (which is `static` by default). So I can set it to `vueappPrefix/static` but of course, this doesn't work.

- expected: `mydomain.com/vueapp/vueappPrefix/static/*`
- what I get: `mydomain.com/vueappPrefix/static`

This is obvious.

Of course I can edit `index.html` by hand or add a script to do it but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about making sub domain or another domain for your VUE app in-which document root points to the `vueapp` folder?

Comment: That would be a good idea, unfortunatly I can't do it. The infrastructure is really specific and doing this will not fit the requirements. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing the `assetsPublicPath` works for me.

In this case, it'd be:

```
assetsPublicPath: '/vueapp/'
```

UPDATE (11/20): To do the same in newer versions of `vue-cli`, there's an option mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I'm ashamed. Thanks a lot !

Comment: if working with vue3-cli, it would be `assetsDir` in `vue.config.js`